# What does the phrase "pull down on" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases, phrasal-verbs

Here is a sentence from a task management app:

> The app allows you to add tasks in several ways and in one of them you
>   can **pull down on** a list to put a task to the top.

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase **pull down on** here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting this question as pertaining to the preposition 'on,' which doesn't appear strictly necessary.

In this case, I imagine "pull down" is used as a fixed expression, and "on" directs the destination of the action - this makes sense to me, if the the language used is in the context of a touch user interface, but I could be wrong.

For another (perhaps better) explanation, here's a question regarding the same set of words from two years ago: [what does ''pull down on'' mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126697/what-does-pull-down-on-mean)